# How to copy the returned token by strtok in c

Tags: c, strtok

When I try to copy the strtok through strcpy as suggested by the other answers on this forum. I don't get the respective number. File format is something like this 43,789,127.0.0.1 on each particular line. However I get 127 in the temp[2] location which should be 127.0.0.1 . What am I missing over here?

```
FILE *f = fopen("somefile", "r");
char *temp[3];
temp[0] = malloc(20);
temp[1] = malloc(20);
temp[2] = malloc(20);
const char s[1] = ",";
char *pch;
if(f != NULL)
{
  char line[1024];
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f) != NULL)
  {
    pch = strtok(line, s);
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
      strcpy(temp[i],pch);
      pch = strtok (NULL, s);
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
} else 
{
  perror("somefile");
}
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
  printf ("%s\n",temp[i]);  
}
```

Comment: `const char s[1] = ",";` --> `const char s[2] = ",";` or `const char s[] = ",";`

Comment: You will only get results from the last line in the file. Previous line data will be overwritten.

Comment: Well i acknowledge that thing already.

Comment: a few comments on the posted code.  1) does not compile, does not even contain any function 2) is missing the needed `#include` statements, 3) missing check for errors on calls to `malloc()`, `fopen()`, `strtok()`.  Note: `perror()` must be called immediately after a function the returned an error indication.  This is because it depends on the value of `errno` which gets updated with each new system function call

Comment: this statement: `for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)` would be much better written as: `for(int i = 0; i<3 && pch; i++)`

Comment: I know that it does not compile since that was trivial to mention over here since i wanted to ask the main problem(its just a snippet to make the problem understandable to others), but thanks anyways for pointing that out. I will try to post the whole  code from the next time. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s` is not a proper C string: `const char s[1] = ",";` defines it to have a size of 1, without a null terminator.

Use this instead:

```
const char *s = ",";
```

Note that a line with fewer than 2 commas will cause the program to have undefined behavior as you do not check that `strtok()` returns a non NULL pointer.  Here is an alternative using `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("somefile", "r");
    char temp[3][20];
    if (fp != NULL) {
        char line[1024];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)  {
            if (sscanf(line, "%19[^,],%19[^,],%19[^\n]", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]) == 3) {
                printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the above code will fail to parse lines with empty fields such as `,,` because `sscanf()` requires a non empty string for the `%[^,]` conversion specifier.

Note also that `strtok()` would be inappropriate for such parsing too as it treats sequences of separators as a single separator, which is OK for white space but probably incorrect for `,`.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. is consistently indented
3. is appropriately horizontally and vertically spaced
4. corrects all the known problems in the posted code
5. properly checks for and handles errors
6. properly displays the parameters from all the lines in the file
7. eliminates unneeded variables

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), fgets(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // strtok(), strcpy()

#define MAX_LENGTH     20
#define MAX_PARAMETERS 3

int main( void )
{
    FILE *f = fopen( "somefile", "r" );
    if( !f )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read somefile failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char *temp[ MAX_PARAMETERS ];

    if( NULL == ( temp[0] = malloc( MAX_LENGTH ) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( NULL == ( temp[1] = malloc( MAX_LENGTH ) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( NULL == ( temp[2] = malloc( MAX_LENGTH ) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char line[1024];
    while( fgets(line, sizeof line, f) )
    {
        int i;
        char *pch = strtok( line, "," );

        for( i = 0; i<3 && pch; i++ )
        {
            strcpy( temp[i], pch );
            pch = strtok ( NULL, "," );
        }

        if( MAX_PARAMETERS != i )
        {
            printf( "failed to extract all parameters from line: %s\n", line );
        }

        else
        {
            for( int j = 0; j<MAX_PARAMETERS; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%s\n", temp[j] );
            }
        }
    }

    fclose( f );
} // end function: main
```